# The Macharius trilogy - is there a statement from William King about the storytelling?

Tags: warhammer-40k

In the Macharius Trilogy 1 Angel of Fire, the story is told from the view of one of Macharius guardsman in review of his life in the guard of Macharius. The first book ends with no stop to that kind of storytelling - you assume the second book "Fist of Demetrius" goes on with it because there is no "end" to his documentation. BUT then... you start the second book with the view of some Dark Eldar Pirate, which feels out of place. And his parts of the story are huge throughout the book.

Sidenote: I didn't read the third book yet so I don't know if he returns to that kind of first person perspective.

With that "error" – that the first book is in first person from the Guardsman, and the second in a split view of both the Alien and the Guardsman – did William King make a mistake?

It doesn't feel right. Maybe it's my German understanding of his English stories, but I feel some kind of disappointment that aspects of book 2 were in the perspective of an Alien. Where the first book built the atmosphere that the storyteller wants to tell it to someone who finds the script after he dies, how could the same person find the scripts of the Alien to complete the story?

TL;DR Did William King make a statement about why he made that choice of this kind of storytelling when his first book in this series was completely different?

Comment: Whether it's an "error" or not is subjective and out-of-scope for this site. Whether or not there is a specific reason that the author has stated for changing perspectives is in-scope. I would edit your question to focus on that aspect.

Comment: I thought i did that by the last sentence... but ok i make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think its mentioned at the start of each book that the guardsman story is to be taken as a larger part of other stories as an investigation into the inquisitor attached to the Macharius crusade. Don't have the books about to check atm

Comment: Did you get your book to check it? Dont have the copy with me either.